# Any errors? My proof that if $\left(A - B\right) \cup \left(B - A\right) = A \cup B$, then $A \cap B = \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

If $A\cup B=(A-B)\cup(B-A)$, then $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

**Proof by Contrapositive**. If $A\cap B\ne\emptyset$, then $A\cup B\ne(A-B)\cup(B-A)$. Suppose that there exists a member of $A\cap B$, $x$. Then, $x\notin(A-B)$ because $x$ is in $B$. Similarly, $x\notin(B-A)$ because $x$ is in $A$. So, $x\notin(A-B)\cup(B-A)$. However, since $x$ belongs to $A$, $x\in A\cup B$. Therefore, $A\cup B\not\subseteq(A-B)\cup(B-A)$, and $A\cup B\ne(A-B)\cup(B-A)$.

Are there any errors or room for improvement in the above proof?

Comment: It should be $A\cup B\supsetneq(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$. The proof is fine from my viewpoint otherwise.

Comment: Proof looks great.  Very clear and simple.

Comment: Im not sure about your first statement.  If non-empty intersection then the union doesnt equal the symmetric difference.  Though true I question whether its obvious enough or are you risking a leap in logic? I guess I just dont know what youve already established and what theorems you are allowed to use at this point.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum I think the first statement is a re-statement of what is to be proved as the contra-positive of the original statement.

Comment: @awllower By the second-last statement, I meant that $A\cup B$ was not a subset of $(A-B)\cup(B-A)$ because not everything that belongs to $A\cup B$ belongs to $(A-B)\cup(B-A)$. Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

$(A - B)\cup(B - A) = (A \cap B^c) \cup (B \cap A^c) =$
$(A \cup B) \cap (A^c \cup B^c) = (A \cup B) - (A \cap B)$
$= A \cup B$
provides a direct proof.

Comment: I'm not sure how you did the recombination, $$(A\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap A^c)=(A\cup B)\cap(A^c\cup B^c)$$. I do know that $$X-Y=X\cap Y^c$$, but don't know how to do the step.

Comment: @YuJinKim Use distributivity of union over intersection.